# AngularJS ng-show directive showing elements before hiding elements

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to create a slide effect for some bootstrap badges I am using to display some hierarchical data relationships using AngularJS.

I have a slider-effect for showing new sub-categories, and hiding sub-categories that are already open. Now this is all working well, except it seems to do the "showing slide" first, and then the "hiding slide" second, which is the opposite of what you would like.

ie. When you hit a badge for a different category, it should first slide closed the already showing other sub-categories, and then open the new sub-categories to be shown.

The html looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <ul ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <li ng-if="category.category_type=='parent'" ng-show="category.category_show">
      <span class="badge badge-p" ng-click="updateResults(category)">{{category.category_name}}</span>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="category.category_type == 'child'" ng-show="category.category_show" class="badge-slider">
      <span class="badge badge-c">{{category.category_name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The relevant CSS looks like this:

```
.badge-slider {
    max-height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height linear 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: max-height linear 0.2s;
    -o-transition: max-height linear 0.2s;
    transition: max-height linear 0.2s;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.badge-slider.ng-hide {
    max-height: 0px;
}
```

I have mocked up a simplified plnkr example to demonstrate what is happening here: http://plnkr.co/edit/S255yk0N2wAXrfq7Mqd6

**EDIT 1:** Thanks to the help of sbedulin I was able to get this working beautifully. I've also updated the code so that the subcategories dynamically indent based on how far down the tree they are. You can find my newly mocked up version here: http://plnkr.co/edit/5I1pU0TZo6AjHJTbBuG9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem is that `<ul ng-repeat="category in categories">` generates multiple `<ul>` elements, `ngRepeat` should be placed on `<li>`s.

After some refactoring HTML will look like:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="category in categories"
        ng-init="isChild = category.category_type == 'child'"
        ng-show="category.category_show"
        class="badge-slider">

      <span ng-click="isChild || updateResults(category)"
            ng-bind="category.category_name"
            class="badge {{ isChild ? 'badge-c' : 'badge-p' }}">
      </span>

    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.badge-slider {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear 0.2s;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.2s linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition:      all 0.2s linear 0.2s;
  transition:         all 0.2s linear 0.2s;

  line-height: 30px;
  overflow:hidden;

  max-height: 30px;
}

.badge-slider.ng-hide {
  transition-delay: 0.0s;

  max-height: 0px;
}
```

Working plunk is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9CiXW1YAoPj80x6PtBW3)

Comment: Thanks sbedulin - that looks great!

Comment: I've been messing around with the example you gave - it works great for 2 types of badges - child and parent. I was wondering how to extend this to three categories of badges - ie. add a "parent and child" category. I don't see how to do this using your example, as it depends on "isChild" to do it's work

Comment: @TomO'Brien `isChild` was introduced for convenience, you may invert it to `isParent` if needed. Can you please provide an example of what's not working and what's the desired output?

Comment: I would like to have a third badge type - badge-pc, which displays elements that are a parent and a child with a different colour. I've created a new Plnkr here, that shows how the subcategories work, but i'm not sure how to modify your code to deal with 3 badge types, when you use the ternary operator on isChild. (Your code works totally perfectly for the question I wrote:)... Here is the new plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/YoRI578GHE91t6torCUt

Comment: Got it :) you'd need to introduce new `$scope.getBadgeClassName` method http://plnkr.co/edit/6CP7Y68QKxfKn26OWOTE?p=preview

Comment: That is a very elegant solution! Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve the desired effect by only modifying your CSS:

```css
/* Styles go here */
.badge-slider {
  max-height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height linear 1.2s;
  -moz-transition: max-height linear 1.2s;
  -o-transition: max-height linear 1.2s;
  transition: max-height linear 1.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.0s;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.badge-slider.ng-hide {
  -webkit-transition: max-height linear 0.0s;
  -moz-transition: max-height linear 0.0s;
  -o-transition: max-height linear 0.0s;
  transition: max-height linear 0.0s;
  max-height: 0px;
}
```

I set your transition lengths to 1.2s in `.badge-slider` just so you can clearly see that it is working. The key is adding in `transition-delay: 0.0s;` to `.badge-slider` and adding transition lengths of 0.0s to `.badge-slider.ng-hide`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks John - that looks pretty nice for the opening, but you still can't see the slider transtition for the hiding of subcategories....

Comment: I want to have the slide effect working for when you close the category... ie. when you click on the parent category if it is open, it will slide closed. At the moment it just abruptly closes, but opens smoothly